# A lightweight and performant way to save audio progress in flutter with just audio

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

I want to save the current track and time location in a [Just Audio playlist](https://suragch.medium.com/managing-playlists-in-flutter-with-just-audio-c4b8f2af12eb?sk=1b1ffa2cb0b3ed50a320d8cc32cef342) in a flutter app.

My current thought is to save the location using something like

```
_audioPlayer.positionStream.listen((event) {
  // update the progress bar in the UI

  // save the location using SharedPreferences
});
```

but I am afraid that this will use a lot of battery life since this function will be run every 16 ms-200 ms. Is there any way to check the battery drain of this one function? And is there any way to save time, but not as often? Would it for instance be better to create another position stream that only runs every 5 seconds? Is there any super failsafe way of saving the location when the user exits the app? Could the solution be to just use another and faster library than [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), like [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)?

Comment: I think you can save the position when `pause/stop` function is called and also if user closes the root without pause/stop then save them in `dispose` method and if user directly closes the app then maybe save using `didChangeAppLifecycleState`. Do test them first